# Nautilus does not display drives properly

Tags: partitioning, nautilus, 12.10, fstab

Nautilus's sidebar partitions broke after a new fstab and an upgrade to Quantal.

I made a new fstab after putting it off for several months, and now Nautilus doesn't show anything in the "Devices" pane.  They still do show up their contents if I manually navigate to `/mnt/whateveriassigneditto`, but I miss quick-and-easy access from the sidebar.  Is this related to my upgrade to 12.10 or something else?  Is there any fix that does **not** involve replacing my UUID references with `/dev/sdax`? (I have very dynamic partitioning layouts; Windows tends to crap out on me often.)

[image: The missing "devices" pane]

My fstab:

```bash
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#
proc                                     /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
#
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=3603e7ad-aa27-4487-acc9-486401fb03cc /               ext4    errors=remount-ro  0       1
#
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=47313ea9-05b2-409c-9954-6664a505d743 none            swap    sw                 0       0
#
# hopefully will mount primary Windows install
UUID=4A5CC6CE5CC6B3CB       /mnt/Windows7    ntfs-3g      quiet,defaults,locale=en_US.utf8,umask=0,exec,user,rw     0 0
#
# Small ramdisk for faster acess times
tmpfs           /mnt/tmpfschk   tmpfs        size=100m                                           0 0
#
#
# Less important volumes:
# Acer Recovery Partition (primary)
UUID=56686A4C686A2AC7       /mnt/Recovery    ntfs-3g      quiet,defaults     0 0
#
# Acer Recovery Partition (logical)
UUID=1C15E94C686A2AC7       /mnt/Recovery2    ntfs-3g      quiet,defaults     0 0
#
# Backup Windows Install (Blank settings and stuff)
UUID=49E82E265CC6B3CB /mnt/WindowsBackup    ntfs-3g      quiet,defaults     0 0
#
#
# Fedora
UUID=6ad48b44-99e9-425b-996f-c6d288dfee79 /mnt/Fedora ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 0
#
# Fedora's Swap Partition
# UUID=9ec7bbb1-2b30-4f8e-9a4a-5355925a3c9d none swap noauto 0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had experience with vanishing menu entries, although in my case it was what I wanted!

I believe the problem is that Nautilus doesn't show external media that aren't mounted under `/media`.  So by mounting under `/mnt` (which, by the way, is usually left as an empty folder to mount to directly in case the sysadmin needs a quick mount point), you are hiding them yourself!

There are two solutions.  First, mount them under `/media`.  This is quick and painless.

Second, you could write a udev rule that tells udisks to recognize them (Nautilus uses udisks IIRC), even though they're mounted somewhere else.  I haven't tried this method, but it might work.  Make a udev rule, like `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-showdrives.rules`, and put in it the following:

```
KERNEL=="sda[0-9]", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="0"
```

Or if you want to use UUIDs (a good idea), have one line looking something like the following **for each of your volumes**.

```
SYMLINK=="disk/by-uuid/YOUR_UUID_HERE", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="0"
```

If the latter doesn't work, rename the file to something like `99-showdrives.rules` to let udev make symlinks.

I adapted this from the opposite advice (which I *have* tried; it works) at
[the Arch Wiki page for KDE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kde#Hiding_partitions).

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  I'll try mounting under Media and seeing whether the double-drive bug still happens in 12.10; if it does I'll try your second method.

Comment: I didn't know that about /mnt; I've only manually done stuff with /mnt with older (Puppy) linux where there was no /media.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, instead of `/mnt`, I usually use openSUSE's convention of mounting Windows volumes under `/windows`.  ("Screw the FHS!" :)  Of course, this will hide your volumes in Nautilus (which is what *I* like).

Comment: Great, drives are all displayed in nautilus's sidebar after mounting under /media/x!  It all works.  (Delay was 'cause I borked my ubuntu by doing something else, I had to edit burg.cfg from fedora.)